# Labels in aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

I need to use the aligned environment to nicely format an equation but I am unable to set a label and a number to one of the equations. How could I achieve this?

```
\begin{align}
    \begin{aligned}
        &&  \text{MSD}  &= 4D \cdot t                  \nonumber \\
        &\Rightarrow    &\frac{\text{MSD}}{t}   &= 4D  \label{eq:diffusion}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why have you got `aligned` there? As it is you just have a single one-line equation in the `align`, with no alignment points specified.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Without the `aligned`, I am unable to get this alignment with the `\Rightarrow`

Comment: but if you use aligned then you should just use `equation` outside not `align` as there is no alignment outside that block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `alignat` unless you need more than one point of alignment (without spaces). In your case, it suffices to use `align`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
                              \text{MSD} &= 4D \cdot t    \nonumber \\
  \Rightarrow \quad \frac{\text{MSD}}{t} &= 4D \label{eq:diffusion}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes I used align initially but tried to get the arrow without explicit space so switched to alignat but ended up using `\quad` anyway. I think I'll leave my answer in place but you should probably get the tick:-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}



alignat
\begin{alignat}{2}
        &&\text{MSD}  &= 4D \cdot t                  \nonumber \\
        \Rightarrow \quad &&\frac{\text{MSD}}{t}  &= 4D  \label{eq:diffusion}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```